# How to create an in-memory object that can be used as a Reader, Writer, or Seek in Rust?

Tags: rust, in-memory

I need a completely in-memory object that I can give to `BufReader` and `BufWriter`. Something like Python's `StringIO`. I want to write to and read from such an object using methods ordinarily used with `File`s.

Is there a way to do this using the standard library?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In fact there is a way: **[`Cursor<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html)!** 
(*please also read [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50732452/2408867) on why often it's even easier*)

In the documentation you can see that there are the following impls:

```
impl<T> Seek for Cursor<T> where T: AsRef<[u8]>
impl<T> Read for Cursor<T> where T: AsRef<[u8]>
impl Write for Cursor<Vec<u8>>
impl<T> AsRef<[T]> for Vec<T>
```

From this you can see that **you can use the type `Cursor<Vec<u8>>` just as an ordinary file**, because `Read`, `Write` and `Seek` are implemented for that type!

Little example ([*Playground*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=af3dce99cac3c24b7fcc7b290de2729d&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
use std::io::{Cursor, Read, Seek, SeekFrom, Write};

// Create fake "file"
let mut c = Cursor::new(Vec::new());

// Write into the "file" and seek to the beginning
c.write_all(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).unwrap();
c.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0)).unwrap();

// Read the "file's" contents into a vector
let mut out = Vec::new();
c.read_to_end(&mut out).unwrap();

println!("{:?}", out);
```

For a more useful example, check the documentation linked above.

Comment: just wondering, would `c.set_position(0)` be equivalent to how you're seeking?

Answer (score 31):

You don't need a `Cursor` *most of the time*.

> object that I can give to `BufReader` and `BufWriter`

`BufReader` requires a value that implements `Read`:

```
impl<R: Read> BufReader<R> {
    pub fn new(inner: R) -> BufReader<R>
}
```

`BufWriter` requires a value that implements `Write`:

```
impl<W: Write> BufWriter<W> {
    pub fn new(inner: W) -> BufWriter<W> {}
}
```

If you view the implementors of [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#implementors) you will find `impl<'a> Read for &'a [u8]`.

If you view the implementors of [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#implementors), you will find `impl Write for Vec<u8>`.

```
use std::io::{Read, Write};

fn main() {
    // Create fake "file"
    let mut file = Vec::new();

    // Write into the "file"
    file.write_all(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).unwrap();

    // Read the "file's" contents into a new vector
    let mut out = Vec::new();
    let mut c = file.as_slice();
    c.read_to_end(&mut out).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", out);
}
```

Writing to a `Vec` will always append to the end. We also take a slice to the `Vec` that we can update. Each read of `c` will advance the slice further and further until it is empty.

The main differences from `Cursor`:

- Cannot seek the data, so you cannot easily re-read data
- Cannot write to anywhere but the end

Comment: This is great. Is it something we couldn't do over a year ago?

Comment: @liszt nope, those implementations existed in Rust 1.0.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use `BufReader` with an in-memory `String`, you can use the `as_bytes()` method:

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::Read;

fn read_buff<R: Read>(mut buffer: BufReader<R>) {
    let mut data = String::new();
    let _ = buffer.read_line(&mut data);

    println!("read_buff got {}", data);
}

fn main() {
    read_buff(BufReader::new("Potato!".as_bytes()));
}
```

This prints `read_buff got Potato!`. There is no need to use a cursor for this case.

To use an in-memory `String` with `BufWriter`, you can use the `as_mut_vec` method. Unfortunately it is `unsafe` and I have not found any other way. I don't like the `Cursor` approach since it consumes the vector and I have not found a way yet to use the `Cursor` together with `BufWriter`.

```
use std::io::BufWriter;
use std::io::Write;

pub fn write_something<W: Write>(mut buf: BufWriter<W>) {
    buf.write("potato".as_bytes());
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::io::{BufWriter};

    #[test]
    fn testing_bufwriter_and_string() {
        let mut s = String::new();

        write_something(unsafe { BufWriter::new(s.as_mut_vec()) });

        assert_eq!("potato", &s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can [get the `Vec` back](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html#method.into_inner) after you are done with the `Cursor`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Great! And then I can use [`from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) to convet to String, `from_utf8` seems to avoid copying of the vector so it should be efficient, could robably also use the `from_utf8_unchecked' which should be a simple move.