# How do I encode a Rust Piston image and get the result in memory?

Tags: image, rust, rust-piston

I am using [the Piston `image` package](https://crates.io/crates/image) to generate images.

```
fn get_image() -> image::DynamicImage {
    image::DynamicImage::ImageRgba8(image::ImageBuffer::new(512, 512))
}
```

I have a [`hyper` web server](https://crates.io/crates/hyper), from which I would like to serve dynamically-generated images.

Based on the answer to *[How to create an in-memory object that can be used as a Reader or Writer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069865/how-to-create-an-in-memory-object-that-can-be-used-as-a-reader-or-writer-in-rust)*, I thought I might be able to use a `Cursor<Vec<u8>>` as the destination. However, `image` only seems to provide a method to write to a filename, not a `Writer` like my cursor.

After looking through `image`'s documentation, I hoped there might be some way to use [the `image::png::PNGEncoder` struct](https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/png/struct.PNGEncoder.html) directly. It provides a public method `encode(self, data: &[u8], width: u32, height: u32, color: ColorType) -> Result<()>`. However, I wasn't sure what the `data` argument is supposed to be, and I couldn't find any public declarations of the `ColorType`s used by `ImageBuffer`.

```
(&Get, "/image.png") => {
    let v = {
        let generated = get_image();
        let mut encoded_image = Cursor::new(Vec::new());
        let (width, heigth) = generated.dimensions();
        {
            let encoder = image::png::PNGEncoder::new(&encoded_image);
            encoder.encode(unimplemented!("what goes here?"));
        }
        encoded_image.get_mut()
    };

    Box::new(futures::future::ok(
        Response::new()
            .with_header(ContentLength(v.len() as u64))
            .with_body(v.clone()),
    ))
}
```

How do I encode [a Piston `GenericImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/trait.GenericImage.html) to a format like PNG and get the result in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> fn getImage() -> image::DynamicImage
> ```

You have a `DynamicImage`.

> image only seems to provide a method to write to a filename

I assume you mean [`DynamicImage::save`](https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.save).

The method immediately before `save` is [`write_to`](https://docs.rs/image/0.19.0/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.write_to):

```
pub fn write_to<W: Write, F: Into<ImageOutputFormat>>(
    &self, 
    w: &mut W, 
    format: F
) -> ImageResult<()>
```

This accepts any generic writer:

```
let mut buf = Vec::new();

get_image()
    .write_to(&mut buf, image::ImageOutputFormat::PNG)
    .expect("Unable to write");
```

There's no need for a `Cursor`.

---

> How do I encode a Piston `GenericImage` to a format like PNG?

I have no idea the best way to do this. I'd probably copy the generic image into a `DynamicImage` and then follow the above instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I've adapted OP's code based on the `image` crate docs. It looks possible to make the original code to work. There is no need for `Cursor` but one needs to create a "by reference" adaptor for the instance of `Write` implemented by `Vec`.

```
// This code have not been tested or even compiled
let v = {
    let generated = get_image();
    let mut encoded_image = Vec::new();
    let (width, height) = generated.dimensions();
    {
        image::png::PNGEncoder::new(encoded_image.by_ref())
            .encode(
                generated.raw_pixels(), 
                width, 
                height,
                generated.color()
            ).expected("error encoding pixels as PNG");
    }
    encoded_image
};
```

Here is the code I actually used in my project. I get a reference to the raw pixels passed in as an `&[u8]` slice. Each pixel represents an 8 bit grayscale value. Here is a function that encodes the pixels into an in memory PNG image.

```
pub fn create_png(pixels: &[u8], dimensions: (usize, usize)) -> Result<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut png_buffer = Vec::new();
    PNGEncoder::new(png_buffer.by_ref())
        .encode(
            pixels,
            dimensions.0 as u32,
            dimensions.1 as u32,
            ColorType::Gray(8),
        ).expect("error encoding pixels as PNG");

    Ok(png_buffer)
}
```

Comment: Add the `use std::io::Write;` to get the Write trait in scope and allow the `by_ref()` to work?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than returning a `DynamicImage` from `get_image`, it would be easier to return a specific image type, for example a colour RGBA image:

```
use image::RgbaImage;

fn get_image() -> RgbaImage {
    RgbaImage::new(512, 512)
}
```

The `RgbaImage` implements `Deref<[u8]>`, which means that the image can be directly dereferenced as a slice of bytes, so `&img` can be used as the first argument to `encode`. The height and width are easy, just access `img.height()` and `img.width()`. The final argument to `encode` is the colour type, which is more fiddly as it is stored as an associated constant of the `Pixel` type parameter on the `ImageBuffer`. From the generic type it can be accessed as `P::COLOR_TYPE`, so instead of making `encode_png` specific to one type of image, I've written it as accepting any `ImageBuffer` type.

The full example is then:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::ops::Deref;
use image::{png::PNGEncoder, ImageBuffer, ImageError, Pixel, RgbaImage, Rgba};

fn encode_png<P, Container>(img: &ImageBuffer<P, Container>) -> Result<Vec<u8>, ImageError>
where
    P: Pixel<Subpixel = u8> + 'static,
    Container: Deref<Target = [P::Subpixel]>,
{
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    let encoder = PNGEncoder::new(&mut buf);
    encoder.encode(img, img.width(), img.height(), P::COLOR_TYPE)?;
    Ok(buf)
}

fn get_image() -> RgbaImage {
    let mut img = RgbaImage::new(32, 32);

    // Draw something to show in the final image
    for i in 0..32 {
        img.put_pixel(i, i, Rgba([255, 0, 0, 255]));
    }
    img
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let img = get_image();
    let buf = encode_png(&img)?;

    // write out the image using the base64 crate as a data
    // URL so that it can be copy-pasted into a web browser
    println!("data:image/png;base64,{}", base64::encode(&buf));
    Ok(())
}
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2611c5ef248667bf984a8dd3cedfec8