# rust image post request

Tags: image, rust, qr-code

I use qrcode-rust which returns its result as image::ImageBuffer. I need to post the png result to thumbor server. How to convert this image buffer to Vec  ?.

I try code below but my `buf` moved and I can do nothing about it.

```
let code = QrCode::new(arg1.as_bytes()).unwrap();
let images = code.render::<Luma<u8>>().build();
let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
let dims = images.dimensions();
let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();

image::png::PNGEncoder::new(buf)
    .encode(&images.into_raw(), dims.0, dims.1, ColorType::Gray(8))
    .expect("Error on encoding to png");

let len = buf.len(); //error here
headers.insert(CONTENT_TYPE, "image/png".parse().unwrap());
headers.insert("Slug", "photo.jpg".parse().unwrap());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "error here"? What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

I copied an answer from [How do I encode a Rust Piston image and get the result in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731636/how-do-i-encode-a-rust-piston-image-and-get-the-result-in-memory) and changed

```
image::png::PNGEncoder::new(buf.by_ref()))
    .encode(
         &images.into_raw(), 
         dims.0, 
         dims.1, 
         ColorType::Gray(8),
    ).expect("Error on encoding to png");
```

And everything works now.