# Cannot use methods from the byteorder crate on an u8 array: no method found for type in the current scope

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a trait provided by the byteorder crate:

```
extern crate byteorder;

use byteorder::{LittleEndian, ReadBytesExt};

fn main() {
    let mut myArray = [0u8; 4];
    myArray = [00000000, 01010101, 00100100, 11011011];

    let result = myArray.read_u32::<LittleEndian>();

    println!("{}", result);
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `read_u32` found for type `[u8; 4]` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:10:26
   |
10 |     let result = myArray.read_u32::<LittleEndian>();
   |                          ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `read_u32` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `[u8; 4] : byteorder::ReadBytesExt`
           `[u8] : byteorder::ReadBytesExt`
```

I've read through the book chapter on traits a couple of times and can't understand why the trait bound isn't satisfied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `[u8]` nor `[u8; 4]` implements [`ReadBytesExt`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.1.0/byteorder/trait.ReadBytesExt.html). As shown [in the documentation](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.1.0/byteorder/index.html), you may use `std::io::Cursor`:

```
let my_array = [0b00000000,0b01010101,0b00100100,0b11011011];
let mut cursor = Cursor::new(my_array);

let result = cursor.read_u32::<LittleEndian>();

println!("{:?}", result);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=176001d6e813a50cbc34adf4b9b1e43d&version=stable&mode=debug)

Any type which implements [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) can be used here, since `ReadBytesExt` [is implemented as](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.1.0/src/byteorder/io.rs.html#888):

```
impl<R: io::Read + ?Sized> ReadBytesExt for R {}
```

Since `&[u8]` implements `Read` you can simplify it to

```
(&my_array[..]).read_u32::<LittleEndian>();
```

or even use the `LittleEndian` trait directly:

```
LittleEndian::read_u32(&my_array);
```

Playgrounds: [`(&my_array)`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0bcd0dea1830e630fe7ba1a6143ece25&version=stable&mode=debug), [`LittleEndian`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5854c268edc866e4d34f92a3be8de882&version=stable&mode=debug)

---

You have some other mistakes in your code:

- `[00000000,01010101,00100100,11011011]` will wrap. Use the [binary literal instead](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/primitives/literals.html): `[0b0000_0000,0b0101_0101,0b0010_0100,0b1101_1011]`
- you should use `_` to make long numbers more readable
- variables should be in `snake_case`. Use `my_array` instead of `myArray`
- You do an unnecessary assignment in the code. Use `let my_array = [0b0000...`

---

See also:

- [You don't need a cursor most of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50732452/155423)